# Is it possible to recover lost rep from someone else getting on my account and giving it away?

Tags: support, reputation

Back in May/June of last year someone (ex. room mate) got on my account and gave away most all of my reputation in the form of bounties... they did this for Movies & TV, Biology and Science Fiction & Fantasy.

When this happened and I found out (was out of town traveling for a couple weeks), it really turned me off to continuing to be an active member of SE. However, over the past few weeks I thought maybe I'd give it a shot of trying to get those rep back.

## Is it possible to submit a ticket to a mod and have them restore the rep that I lost (now just talking about Movies & TV SE)?

We're talking about some **5000 rep** that they gave away in the span of just a few days.

Comment: I doubt it. **At the end, account security is your responsibility.**  How would the Community Manager (a mod couldn't do it) tell that the rep was given away fraudulently as opposed to a regretted whim.

Comment: @Paulie_D There wouldn't be any definitive way of the Community Manager knowing. Doesn't hurt to ask though...!

Comment: That is rough.  I wouldn't delete this message - you never know if a CM might see it and take pity.

Comment: @iandotkelly Okay!

Comment: It was actually like 8,000 rep. Yikes!

Comment: I would probably ask on the overarching stack meta. You never know

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid you might be out of luck here.

I won't claim to know all the odds and ends of weird events in 10 years of SE history, but I very much **doubt there's a way for you to get that reputation back**. There's two problems to this. The moderators and/or SE employees have absolutely nothing but your word to prove that it was actually your roommate that did this rather than you just changing your mind. We might *want* to not insinuate you lying, but we can't really trust you blindly either, I'm afraid. You might not know, but it's quite often a "roommate", "brother" or a "coworker" that does the things people get suspended for. ;-)

But even if that was really the case, it's ultimately irrelevant since it would still hinge upon **your own responsibility to give your roommate access to your account**, willingly or not.

And in addition to that, it would also be a little unfair to rob the users who got these bounties of their awards now. Granted, we rob people of rep all the livelong day when they answer questions that get closed and deleted. Still, the bounties *seemed* legit (when bounties of such high amounts are given away, we tend to check it's not something shady and the answers that got rewarded seemed largely reasonable).

So on the bottom line, you might have to live with that unlucky incident. I hope you still can bring the motivation to continue SEing, though. Judging from your contributions, it might not take you that long to get your reputation up to par again.